# If PostMessage Succeeded, is the message guaranteed to be processed by the window?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a background thread to process data and want to send the result to the main Window, but the window may be destroyed before the background thread exits.

I use `PostMessage` to deliver some newly created objects (created in heap), if it succeed, does the message get processed by the main Window surely?

If not, what is the best practice for this kind of situation?

ps: My concern is that when posting messages, the Window is valid, but then it is destroyed before the message get delivered. If so, I cannot `delete` the objects.

Comment: Don't send dynamic objects to the window; post them to a queue (such as a `std::queue`) that is synchronized on the push, then post a *notification* (could be any WM_USER or registered window message) to the window to check the queue (which it will synchronize on the pull-out). If the window is shut down prematurely, the caller can stop pushing data in and simply clean out the queue and its content. You may also find you don't need dynamic pointers for this (which would be smart pointers anyway if you pursue this logic).

Comment: @WhozCraig Messages in the range `WM_USER` to `WM_APP-1` are reserved for use by implementers of a window class (like the Edit control). Don't use messages in this range for in-process communication. The `WM_APP+x` range of messages is reserved for this purpose.

Comment: @IInspectable that totally makes sense. I've been so-long out of Windows programming some of it is a giant fog at this point. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

> I use PostMessage to deliver some newly created objects (created in heap), if it succeed, does the message get processed by the main Window surely?

If the call to `PostMessage` succeeds, then the message is placed in the queue. The message will then be processed when the thread pumps its message queue. If the thread fails to pump its queue, or if the recipient window no longer exists when the message is processed, then it will not be delivered.